# counting elements of order k in a group

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of Cyclic Subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77314/order-of-cyclic-subgroups)

If I have a group G where $\vert G \vert = n$ and I want to calculate the number of the elements in G of order n can I then deduce the following statement?

> If G is a cyclic group then the number is $\phi (n)$ (Euler's totient function)
>
> else the number is 0

?

Comment: How can we know if you *can* deduce it? I think that you are rather trying to ask if that statement is true and, in that case, how to prove it...

Comment: This is very, very far from true. Did you try any examples?

Comment: How could the number be independent of $k$?

Comment: If the group is not cyclic, do you think there is no element of ANY order? ;)

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: If you are asking whether the statement is true, then the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true; that is:

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Then either $G$ is cyclic and has exactly $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$, or else $G$ is not cyclic and has no elements of order $n$.

*Proof.* $\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $|g|$ for each $g\in G$. By definition, $G$ is cyclic if and only if there exists $g\in G$ such that $\langle g\rangle = G$. So for $G$ of order $n$ we have:
$$\begin{align*}
G\text{ is cyclic} &\iff \text{there exists }g\in G\text{ such that }\langle g\rangle = G\\
&\iff\text{there exists }g\in G\text{ such that }|\langle g\rangle|=|G|\\
&\iff \text{there exists }g\in G\text{ such that }|\langle g\rangle = n\\
&\iff\text{there exists }g\in G\text{ such that }|g|=n.
\end{align*}$$
Thus, if $G$ is *not* cyclic, then there are *no* elments of order $n$. If $G$ *is* cyclic, then there is at least one element of order $n$, and every element is of the form $g^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, which we may assume satisfies $0\leq k\lt n$ (prove it!). Since $|g^k| = n/\gcd(n,k)$ (prove it!), then the number of elements of order $n$ is the number of integers $k$ such that $0\leq k\lt n$ and $n/\gcd(n,k)=n$, which is the number of integers $k$ such that $0\leq k\lt n$ and $\gcd(n,k) = 1$.