# $g^k$ is a primitive element modulo $m$ iff $\gcd (k,\varphi(m))=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'd really love your help with the following one:
: Let $g$ a primitive element modulo $m$, $g^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1\pmod{m}$. I need to prove that  $g^k$ is a primitive element modulo $m$ iff $\gcd (k,\varphi(m))=1$.

First I tried to assume the left part, since $g^k$ is a primitive element so $g^k \equiv 1\pmod{m}$, so that $k \neq \varphi(m) $. so there is a $r$ such that $r| \varphi(m)$, $r|k$.

if $k=r$ so $\varphi(m)=kt$ for some $t$, $t < \varphi(m)$ so that $1 \equiv g^{\varphi(m)}=g^{kt}=(g^{k})^t$ so $g^k$ is not an primitive element. if $k \neq r$  so there are $a,b$ such that $\varphi(m)a+kb=r$ for $r\gt 1$, what can I do next?

I succeeded the other direction.

Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of Cyclic Subgroups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77314/order-of-cyclic-subgroups)

Comment: @lhf But, alas, the single answer to that question simply states the result without proof, so this should not be closed as a duplicate of *that*. But I do recall other answers covering this ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $d=\gcd(k,\varphi(m))$.

$$\begin{align*}
(g^k)^{\ell}\equiv 1\pmod{m} &\iff g^{k\ell}\equiv 1\pmod{m}\\
&\iff \varphi(m)\text{ divides }k\ell\\
&\iff \frac{\varphi(m)}{d}d\text{ divides } \frac{k}{d}d\ell\\
&\iff \frac{\varphi(m)}{d}\text{ divides }\frac{k}{d}\ell\\
&\iff \frac{\varphi(m)}{d}\text{ divides }\ell,
\end{align*}$$
since 
$$\gcd\left(\frac{\varphi(m)}{d},\frac{k}{d}\right) = \frac{1}{d}\gcd(\varphi(m),k) = 1.$$

This in fact tells you the order of $g^k$ modulo $m$ for any $g$; more generally, it tells you that if you know the order of $g$, then you can compute the order of $g^k$ for any $k$, whether $g$ is a primitive root or not.

In fact, this is a special case of the result from basic Group Theory: if $a$ has order $m$, then $a^k$ has order $m/\gcd(m,k)$.

---

For your attempt: it is incorrect when you say that if $g^k$ is a primitive element then $g^k\equiv 1\pmod{m}$; that would imply that $\varphi(m)|k$, not that $g^k$ is a primitive element.

You don't want to use the fact that $\gcd(k,\varphi(m))$ is a linear combination of $k$ and $\varphi(m)$, you want to use the fact that $k\varphi(m)/r$ is the least common multiple of $k$ and $\varphi(m)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidinThanks for your as always really helpful explanations. Maybe there's a typo in the last equality, gcd(...,k) rather than d.

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed there was a typo, thanks.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thank you for the answer. I wanted to ask you, continuing my answer, if $ k \neq r$ so $\varphi(m)a+kb=r$ and $g^{\varphi(m)a}g^{kb}=g^r$ so  $kb=r$ so $k|r$ but $r|k$ so $k=r$ but if $k=r$ we already got a contradiction, will it do for proving the left to the right direction?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:Is it not the case that g must also be prime to m? Thanks

Comment: @Andrew: Yes; it is implied in "$g$ is a primitive element modulo $m$". But it's really irrelevant to the argument: if the order of $g$ is $t$, then the order of $g^k$ is $t/\gcd(t,k)$, whatever $t$, $g$, and $k$ may be.

Comment: @Jozef: No, you cannot conclude that $kb=r$; you can only conclude that $kb\equiv r\pmod{\varphi(m)}$, but you already knew that. You are looking at the *wrong* relationship:  it's not the fact that you can write $r$ as a linear combination of $k$ and $\varphi(m)$ that gives you the result here. What you want to use is the fact that $r$ is a common divisor of $k$ and $\varphi(m)$. Write $k=r\kappa$, $\varphi(m)=rt$. Then what is $(g^k)^t$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ g^{kn}\! = 1\iff \varphi\: |\: kn\iff \varphi\: |\: kn,\varphi n\iff \varphi\: |\: (kn,\varphi n) = (k,\varphi)n\iff \smash[b]{\dfrac{\varphi}{(k,\varphi)} \bigg|\: n}$

Therefore $\rm\: g^k\:$ has order $\rm\:\varphi/(k,\varphi),\:$ which $\rm = \varphi\iff (k,\varphi) = 1.\ \  \ $ **QED**

Alternatively, one can give a dual proof, employing $\rm\ [k,\varphi] :=\: lcm(k,\varphi)$

Then $\rm\:\ g^{kn}\! = 1\iff \varphi\: |\: kn\iff k, \varphi\: |\: kn\iff [k,\varphi]\: |\: kn\iff \smash[t]{\dfrac{[k,\varphi]}k\bigg|\:n}$

The two proofs are equivalent [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) $\rm\:k\varphi = (k,\varphi)[k,\varphi]\: \Rightarrow\: \smash{\dfrac{\varphi}{(k,\varphi)} = \dfrac{[k,\varphi]}k}$

**Remark** $\: $ The efficiency of the above proof stems from use of the universal bidirectional $(\!\!\!\iff\!\!\!)$ characterizations of GCD, LCM, viz. in any integral domain one has these universal definitions

**Definition** of **LCM** $\quad$ If $\quad\rm a,b\:|\:c \;\iff\; [a,b]\:|\:c \quad\;$ then $\quad\rm [a,b] \;$ is an **LCM** of $\:\rm a,b$

**Definition** of **GCD** $\quad$ If $\quad\rm c\:|\:a,b \;\iff\; c\:|\:(a,b) \quad$ then $\quad\rm (a,b) \;$ is an **GCD** of $\:\rm a,b$

For many further examples see [my posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com+dubuque%2Buniversal%2Bgcd%2Blcm) emphasizing these universal properties of GCD, LCM. Many proofs in number theory become *mechanical* after one masters these properties.