# If $\operatorname{ord}_ma=10$, find $\operatorname{ord}_ma^6$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $\operatorname{ord}_ma=10$, find $\operatorname{ord}_ma^6$.  Justify you're answer.

I'm not sure what I should say for my answer to be justified.  However, I expect $\operatorname{ord}_ma^6=5$, because $5\cdot 6=30$ and $10\mid 30$.

Like I said, no idea if this is how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: I expect that this, together with "No lower positive multiple of $6$ is divisible by $10$" should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$ord_ma=d, ord_m(a^k)=\frac{d}{(d,k)}$$ ([Proof](http://archive.org/details/NumberTheory_862) @Page#95)

Here $$d=10,k=6\implies  ord_m(a^6)=\frac{10}{(10,6)}=\frac{10}2=5$$

Comment: The linked proof is also on our site, e.g. see [this simpler one-line proof.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/134139/242)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\ ord\ a\, = 10\:$ then $\rm\:a^{6n}\equiv 1\iff 10\mid 6n\iff 5\mid 3n\iff 5\mid n.$

**Remark** $\ $ Above we invoked: $\ $ if $\rm\:ord\ a\, = k\:$ then $\rm\:a^n\equiv 1\iff k\mid n.\:$ This can be viewed much more conceptually: the set $\cal O$ of integers $\rm\,n\,$ with $\rm\:a^n\equiv 1\:$ is *closed under subtraction,* hence, by a [fundamental theorem,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) every element of $\cal O$ is a multiple of the *least* positive element of $\cal O,\,$ which in our case is called the *order*.