# Given one primitive root, how do you find all the others?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example:  if $5$ is a primitive root of $p = 23$.

Since $p$ is a prime there are $\phi(p - 1)$ primitive roots. Is this correct?

If so, $\phi(p - 1) = \phi(22) = \phi(2) \phi(11) = 10$.  So $23$ should have $10$ primitive roots?

And, to find all the other primitive roots we need powers of $5$, say $k$, sucht that $gcd(k, p - 1) = d> 1$.  Again, please let me know If this true or not

So, the possible powers of $5$ are: $1, 2, 11, 22$.  But this only gives four other primitive roots.  So I don't think I'm on right path.

Comment: You want $\gcd(k,p-1)=1$.

Comment: There are $\phi(n)$ primitive $n$th roots of unity. For a prime $p$, this means that there are $\phi(p)=p-1$ of them.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $d=ord_ma,$ we know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229150/if-operatornameord-ma-10-find-operatornameord-ma6/229643#229643) $ord_m(a^n)=\frac d{(n,d)}$ where $m,d$ are positive integers  and $a,n$  are integers

If $a$ is a primitive root $\pmod m, ord_ma=\phi(m)$

(Remember all integers may not have a primitive root )

So, $ord_m(a^n)=\frac {\phi(m)}{(n,\phi(m))}$

So,  $a^n$ is a primitive root $\pmod m,$ if $ord_m(a^n)=\phi(m)$ which needs $(n,\phi(m))=1$

If $m$ is prime, $\phi(m)=m-1$

Comment: @icanc, observe that there are exactly $\phi(\phi(m))$ values of $n,$ including $\pm1$ such that $ord_m(a^n)=ord_ma=\phi(m)$ resulting in same number of primitive roots

Answer (score 2):

You simply need $\,k\,$ such that $$\gcd(k, p-1) = 1$$

Recall that there are $\varphi (n)$ *primitive* $n$-th *roots of unity*.  And for any prime $\,p,\;$ we know there are $\varphi(p)=p−1\;$ such roots.

---

For a more detailed explanation of why [$g^k$ is a primitive root modulo n if **$\gcd(k, \varphi(n)) = 1$**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134109/gk-is-a-primitive-element-modulo-m-iff-gcd-k-varphim-1?lq=1), see particularly the answer by Arturo Magidin.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are going wrong is the part where you said that $\gcd(k,p−1) = d > 1$. 
Infact, what you want is $\gcd(k,p-1) = 1$. 
After you've found the first primitive root  $= 5$ , the powers of $5$ will be the elements in $\phi(\phi(23)) = \phi(22) = \{1,3,5,7,9,13,15,17,19,21\}$.

This will give the required 10 primitive roots.

Answer (score -2):

The possible powers of 5 are all the $k$'s that $gcd(k,p−1)=1$, so $k$ is in the set {$1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21$} and $5^k$ is in the set {$5, 10, 20, 17, 11, 21, 19, 15, 7, 14$} which is exactly of length 10.