# if $b^k$ is a primitive root, then $b$ is a primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Any hints or strategies would be greatly appreciated:

> If $m$ is an integer and $b^k$ is a primitive root mod $m$, then $b$ is a primitive root mod $m$.

I am reviewing material from my elementary number theory course.  I had a true/false question that I think is true (by process of elimination of how many "trues" the problem set was supposed to have).  But I and am absolutely stuck on trying to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and please use Latex to format your equations. (Put them between a pair of $'s).

Comment: Almost always start with the question, not your life story.

Comment: How does your material define "primitive root"?

Comment: Have you tried contraposition? Instead of "$b^k$ primitive $\implies$ $b $ primitive", try proving "$b $ not primitve $ \implies $ $b^k$ not primitive".

Comment: Text is Rosen.  Definition is:  If $r$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers with $n > 0$ and if $ord_n r = phi(n)$, then $r$ is called a primitive root mod $n$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134109/gk-is-a-primitive-element-modulo-m-iff-gcd-k-varphim-1

Comment: Many thanks to all responders for ideas and help.  I think I almost have a proof of the contrapositive.

Answer (score 2):

If powers of $b^k$ generate every coprime residue class mod m, then powers of $b$, which powers are a superset of the first set of powers, also generate every coprime residue class mod m.  So $b$ is also a primitive root.  (A coprime residue class mod m is an invertible one, i.e., $\{a|(a,m)=1\}$.)